# Retail shop got my email address and sent me ads based on my activities

Tags: network, email, spam

I visited Germany this weekend and I didn't provide my email address to anyone or to any website while I was there, neither to any service related to my visit there.

I never connected to public Wi-Fi networks, only to 3G and to one private Wi-Fi of the apartment where I stayed for the night (password protected).

After 24 hours of arriving to Germany, I received an email advertising a German retail store with some articles related to my activities there.

This was only my second time to Germany, and I never provided any of personal details to any place there.

I do not have Facebook account or similar social network. I do have "Google voice search" activated on my phone (the "OK Google:..." thing).

To summarize my question: How is it possible for a retail shopping company to  get a person's email address and do targeted advertisment, without the person ever provided it with its personal data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways this could have happend, but here is one:

Some advertising network has your email address. How they got it is impossible for me to say, but it can very well have happend long before you set foot in Germany. Perhaps you signed up for a newsletter somewhere three years ago.

That ad network has a cookie stored in your browser, that identifies you and connects you to the email they somehow got from you. When you are in Germany you visit a site that includes some ad from that network. Your cookie is then sent to them. From the IP they can tell that you are in Germany. What a great opportunity to send you some German shopping tips!

Comment: Or the airline. Or your phone using SMS. Or...

Comment: @RoryAlsop Actually, I got there by train. I don't think it was with cookies from the browser, given that I have 3rd party cookies blocked and I expect the cookies policy of the sites I visit to be less invasive that this... Maybe I am being a bit naive

Comment: If you have google enabled, then there's your likely answer.